# Python requests stream issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a question about python requests.

When i request to the [link](http://cms.stream.publicradio.org/) using python requests, the application freezes at the requests `get()` method statement. My guess is that the application stays in a loop on the `get` method because the page did not load completely.

I sharing below code sample:

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0'}
print('request sending')
ctt = requests.get('http://cms.stream.publicradio.org/', verify=False, timeout=20,
                         headers=headers, stream = False).headers.get('Content-Type')
print('###' + ctt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `stream` as True:

```
res = requests.get('http://cms.stream.publicradio.org/', verify=False, timeout=20,
                         headers=headers, stream=True)
print res.headers.get('Content-Type')  # it will print 'audio/mpeg'
```